# How to limit CPU usage in queue with redis server in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, redis

I implemented queue for report generation in my Laravel 4.2 application. I used redis as queue server. To start queue listen I used command, 
`php artisan queue:listen --timeout=0 --sleep=10`
But when report generation starts, means if I push some job into queue, server CPU goes to `100%`. So other web applications in the same server become down. How can  I limit CPU usage for each web application or how can I limit CPU usage for redis queue?  Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,
Manu

Comment: Have you considered having another server generating the reports? You could have a separate machine processing the queues, that won't affect the webservers when they start generating the reports.